# How To Get Balance in a Program

Tags: anchor, solana-program, program

Is it possible to get SOL balance and/or SPL token balances for a given account in an Anchor program?

Answer (score 6):

The lamports of an account in Anchor can be found with:

```
let lmps: u64 = ctx.accounts.my_account.to_account_info().lamports();
```

If you have an account that is defined as `Account<'info, anchor_spl::token::TokenAccount>`, you can get the amount of SPL tokens stored in that account with:

```
let amt: u64 = ctx.accounts.my_token_account.amount;
```